# Integral of $\int \frac{16}{4x+x \sqrt{x}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to find the integral

$$\int \frac{16}{4x+x \sqrt{x}}dx$$

I tried different $u$ substitutions.

When I substitute $u$ for $\sqrt{x}$, $du = 1/(2\sqrt{x}) = 1/2u$

and I'm left with $16$ times the integral of $1/(8u^3+u^4)$.

Using partial fractions, I get $16$ times the integral of

$1/(8u)-1/(4u^2)+1/(2u^3)-1/(8(u+2))$,

which equals

$$16(\ln|\sqrt{x}|) + 1/(4\sqrt{x}) -1/x - 1/8 \ln(|\sqrt{x}+2|)+C$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a couple of mistakes during the substitution.

$du = \frac{1}{2u} \: dx$ is right, but what then? What do you need to replace $dx$ with?

And then you are subbing in the wrong $u's$ in the integrand.

Substitute
$u = \sqrt{x}$

$$\int \frac{16}{4x+x\sqrt{x}}dx = 32 \int \frac{1}{u(u+4)}du$$

partial fractions
$$= -8 \int \frac{1}{u+4}du + 8 \int \frac{1}{u}du$$

$$=8 \ln (u) - 8 \ln(u+4)$$

substitute back

$$=4\ln \sqrt{x} - 8\ln(\sqrt{x} + 4) + C$$

Answer (score 0):

If I may suggest, in order to avoid this kind of mistakes, a rather systematic approach could be (this is the way I learnt it long time ago) $$u=f(x)\implies x=g(u)\implies dx=g'(u)\,du$$ and replace. If you notice, after deciding about the change of variable, $u$ is always in the right hand side.

In the present case $$u=\sqrt x \implies x=u^2 \implies dx=2u\,du$$

$$\int \frac{16}{4x+x \sqrt{x}}dx=\int \frac{16}{4u^2+u^2 \times u}\, 2u\,du=\int\frac{32}{u^2+4 u}\,du$$ The remaining is explained by JKnecht in his/her answer.